# Robocopy created hidden directory at destination

Tags: powershell, backup, robocopy

I can't see the directory "Backup" in Windows Explorer, although I can navigate to it. The same is true for PowerShell. When I go to the root of the directory `Dad` and type `ls` I don't see it in the list.  I can however `cd` to `Backup`, as shown in the screenshot.

How can I make the directory `Backup` visible? I have `Hidden Items` checked, but it's still invisible! I've never experienced this before. All the files and subdirectories copied over as expected, but they are hidden on the `E` drive.

The directory was created via a mirror of my `D` drive:

```
Robocopy D:\ "E:\Dad\Backup" /MIR /FFT /Z /XA:H /W:5
```

[image: Hidden "Backup" Directory]

Comment: Can you do a `Get-ChildItem -Force` in that dad directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The directory was created via a mirror of my d drive: Robocopy D:\ "E:\Dad\Backup" /MIR /FFT /Z /XA:H /W:5

It’s been a while since I’ve dealt with this and don’t remember the exact solution I used. But it appears you’re running in to the same issue with Robocopy.

If you copy from a root directory, like `D:\` the destination folder will be marked with a hidden and system attribute.

After the operation you can solve this with: `attrib -s -h E:\Dad\Backup`

Before the operation, you can prevent this by adding the `/A-:SH` switch to the robocopy command line: `Robocopy D:\ "E:\Dad\Backup" /MIR /FFT /Z /XA:H /W:5 /A-:SH`

Additionally, if you want to see these folders, you can turn on the option to show hidden files AND to not hide special operating system folders. Or use the `dir /a` command.

Answer (score 1):

There are Hidden as well as System folders. This is likely a system folder.

Type `dir` and see if it has a `s` in it, like this:

> d---s-        10/16/2021   9:48 PM                Backup

then type `attrib -s E:\Dad\Backup` to remove the System attribute.